# wrong string to timestamp conversion in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I tried to convert the string `"01/03/2019 0:10:00"` to a timestamp and the result I got was `1551395400` which is incorrect. This timestamp is equivalent to `28/02/2019 11:00:00`.

I don´t understand why I am getting this issue, yesterday on the same computer the conversion was correct.

The code:

```
date ="01/03/2019 0:10:00"
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S).timetuple())
```

Comment: When I run that code the output I get is 1551399000.0 which comes back as the correct time. Sounds like you might not be considering timezones?

Comment: Did your local time zone change, or did you change some setting on your computer related to time zones?

Comment: I don't change nothing.

Comment: I realize when i insert data in a database and I get an error of unique constraint

Comment: You example has a missing double quote, so it can't be exactly what you ran.  It might be informative to get a screen capture of exactly what you are running and the output.  Here's mine (which differs from greg_data by 5 hours because of timezone differences).

>>> date ="01/03/2019 0:10:00"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
1551417000.0

Comment: i just saw the problem is the timezone. I looked at a web page and it told me that timestamp was 02/28/2019 11:00 and it is wrong. The timestamp is 28/02/2019 23:10 and my time zone at that time was gmt + 1.
but I don't understand how executing that code 2 days ago without any changes gave me another timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The hour has one zero, but is described as `%H`?

Comment: Changing it to `00:` has no effect, so I don't think this is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a timezone problem. Try this :

```
import pytz, datetime
local = pytz.timezone ("Europe/Paris") # Put your timezone
date ="01/03/2019 0:10:00"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
local_dt = local.localize(dt, is_dst=None)
utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Then you can call :

```
datetime.datetime.timestamp(utc_dt)
```

Comment: So is. Thank you very much.

Comment: But now I have another problem. python says that datetime.datetime has no attribute timestamp

Comment: Well it's weird. Make sure you've successfully imported the datetime module. Check this website out : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/timestamp-datetime for some information on the conversion of a datetime object to a timestamp.